# how to receive a POST data in a python file

Tags: python, html

I have to receive a POST data from browser to a python file . suppose i want to post username and userID  I am using Python with mod_python . So please some one tell me how to POST data as query through browser and how to receive it in py file . I am new to python .

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027596/mod-python-get-post-parameters-from-request-object

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you drop mod_python as it has been long deprecated. Use something like Flask (with mod_wsgi).

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods="POST")
def hello_post():
    # if we have a form
    if request.form:
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: thats the problem i am not allowed to use any web framework in it . and i have to use mod_python .